# python trying to pass list in as variable in function TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass a list in as a variable (var1) but I keep getting TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. So I added a list comprehension thinking I need to make it iterate in order for it to sum. It didn't work, I'm not sure what the type error means exactly if it doesn't mean that I need to iterate over the list from var1. The splat works, it converts the tuple to a list then sums the list. It just won't work for a given list as var1.

```
    class MathDojo(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.count = 0

        def add(self,var1,*args):
            self.var1 = var1
            self.var1 = [x for x in self.var1, sum(self.var1)]
            self.args = list(args)
            self.args = sum(self.args)
            self.count += (self.var1 + self.args)
            return self


        def subtract(self,var1,*args):
            self.var1 = var1
            self.var1 = sum(self.var1)
            self.args = list(args)
            self.args = sum(self.args)
            self.count += -(self.var1 + self.args)
            return self

        def result(self):
            print self.count
            return self

    test = MathDojo()
    test.add(2,2,2).subtract([3,2,1],3,1,2).add(1,3,5,6,7).subtract(3,4,6).result()


    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "mathdojo.py", line 26, in <module>
        test.add(2,2,2).subtract([3,2,1],3,1,2).add(1,3,5,6,7).subtract(3,4,6).result()
      File "mathdojo.py", line 6, in add
        self.var1 = [x for x in var1, sum(var1)]
    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here. `add` is presumably some method in a class definition? What should this method do? If you are trying to find the sum of the list `var1` then all you need is `sum(var1)`...

Comment: It would be nice to show where you call that function and with which arguments. Chances are as the error states that you are passing an int and not a list...

Comment: sorry i didnt want to include too much code for readability. Ill include it all

Comment: Also, which line gives error?

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the seventh line does             self.var1 = [x for x in self.var1, sum(self.var1)]
ill include error code

Comment: What is this line supposed to do: `self.var1 = [x for x in self.var1, sum(self.var1)]`? I think that's your error

Comment: What in the world are you doing with your instance attributes? Why do you keep reassigning to them, and then never really using them and they don't really seem to serve any purpose other than to obfuscate your code...

Comment: even without the list comprehension it brings up the same issue. i used a list comprehension because i thought the error meant it wasnt iterating because it wasnt given an action to iterate

Comment: When you get the error, `var1` is `2`, which is an integer and so isn't iterable...

Comment: there shouldnt be any issue with me reassigning my function variables, the issue is the type error. i can make it pretty later

Comment: okay i did if isinstance(var,list): then sum. thank you thierry. would vote you right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test.add(2,2,2)` will make var1 to be equal to 2. 2 is not a list, so the line `x for x in self.var1, sum(self.var1)` will have an error, because both for and sum requires list and 2 is an integer. You can use `test.add([2,2,2])`

Comment: Thank you, Thierry helped first but it's the same work

Answer (score 0):

This will serve your purpose:

`self.var1 = [x for x in range(self.var1)]`

`self.var1.append(sum(self.var1))`

But later part of your code has many other bugs. So I wonder the code will run without fixing them.